# Read XML from memory in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

i want to be able to fill in a form using an XML file from the user.

how can i have them upload the XML file to read, without actually saving it to the server? is it possible?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are talking about an html form right?

Comment: What kind of server are you uploading to?  Are you sure that this can't be performed on the client side?

Comment: how? basically all i need is to be able to get the file contents without actually having to upload it to the server...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about an ASP.NET web application here.

Most dictionaries define the term upload as something like "copy or transfer (data or a program) from one's own computer into the memory or storage of another computer". If you are uploading, you are in other words moving it to the server. I am therefore also assuming that what you are *really* asking for is how to upload without storing the file on the server's *file system*.

Files can be uploaded to a server using the [FileUpload Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227669%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

The uploaded file becomes a file of type `HttpPostedFile` on the server.

You can read the `HttpPostedFile.InputStream` property [`MyFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream`](e.g. with some sort of `XmlReader`) without involving intermediary storage of the file on the server's file system.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file stream, then you can use a XmlTextReader.

Here's an [example](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/mahesh/xmlusingvbdotnet04222005015518am/xmlusingvbdotnet.aspx) on how to work with the XmlTextReader.  In the example, they use the file name in the constructor of the XmlTextReader but you can also pass your file stream.